# Java FixedThreadPool waiting thread context switch

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have 3 fixedThreadPools in my application with size of 20 each.

I submit the tasks in pools but they are few sometimes say 5 task in each pool1 ,pool2 ,pool 3 so I have 15 threads from each pool sitting idle. I want to know does these idle threads (45 total) will come in context switch and degrade the performance even when no task is submitted to them ?

Comment: The idle threads shouldn't get scheduled. Profiling your application is the best way to check. It sounds like you could very well, change that value of 20 and see if it affects the performance.

Comment: just use `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` to get visual timeline of your threads activity.

Answer (score 3):

If the pooled threads have no task, they are in state [WAITING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING), meaning they have nothing to do besides wait for a signal for something to happen (in this case, waiting for a task to be submitted). They don't get scheduled any CPU time because they have nothing to do. The scheduler is smart enough to know this, so it's at this point where it's excluded from competing for resources with other, more active threads.

If a thread is in `RUNNABLE` state, then it might have something to actually do, and is given CPU time.

So excess threads in a pool don't compete with live threads, but they do take a small amount of native resources (not enough to really matter when talking about 60 threads).

Answer (score 2):

> I have 3 fixedThreadPools in my application with size of 20 each.

You mean, you are creating 3 `ExecutorService` instance of thread pool size `20`. That means total `60` threads in pools ?

> ...15 threads from each pool sitting idle. I want to know does these
>   idle threads (45 total) will come in context switch..

I think, you are assuming to run all 60 threads at the same time, as you have mentioned 5 thread from each pool (i.e 15 threads) are executing. But remaining 45 threads (15 thread from each pool) are idle. But, that is not correct until they have tasks assign **and** number of available cores to execute them.

Please note, execution of thread depends on number of available cores (CPU). No matter, how many thread you create, if CPU is not available to execute each thread, they will be at `Runnable` state to get their turn.

JVM who decides which thread should run and how, mainly uses preemptive or time slicing scheduling to schedule the threads. In that time, if other thread get a new task (or has some task to execute), then they will at `Runnable` state to get their turn.

Comment: Threads that have nothing to do won't be waiting to get their turn. as the scheduler won't even consider them when dealing out CPU time. Pools can easily be larger than `availableProcessors()` as most tasks aren't 100% CPU bound, so this is a bad (but common) suggestion. A suitable pool size depends on many things, so you can't really suggest a proper pool size without knowing the environment, problem etc.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your feedback, *Threads that have nothing to do won't be waiting to get their turn* No, I meant, if there are not CPU available, then they will be waiting for their turn. isn't it correct ?

Comment: But that's not what was asked. Of course you need to actually have a free core to run a thread, that goes without saying. It's only `RUNNABLE` threads that are waiting to get time on a core, `WAITING` threads don't even get that far until they become `RUNNABLE`.

Comment: @Kayaman pls do let me know, if I have corrected this. I just shared my understanding as an answer. You can help me improving my knowledge :-) Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: While the question certainly isn't the clearest, you're not really answering what he's asking: is it "slower" if you submit  (only) 1 task into a pool of 100 threads vs. a pool of 2 threads.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other executors, ForkJoinPool supports [work stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing).
Yes, when there are no tasks for execution threads would be waiting, but before that, they try to steal works from pool's queues, and this will consume more CPU, then other executors (FixedThreadPool, CachedThreadPool). And waking up threads also needs time.

ForkJoinPool performs best when it has a lot job. If you don't have this, you better to use FixedThreadPool. Also, you should understand that typically ForkJoinPool, FixedThreadPool are for CPU intensive tasks. Otherwise, if you have IO intensive tasks is better to use CachedThreadPool. You could create one FixedThreadPool at all, but should aware that tasks could block each other.

Also, there is no reason create three ForkJoinPool pools with 60 threads unless you have at least 32 CPUs (but it hugely depends). As you can not utilize pools, that it is likely not your example. But keep in mind, if you run a lot of CPU intensive tasks in thread's count bigger then CPUs, then yes, you likely get worse performance, because of resource sharing, including context switches.